# Maximum number of points of intersection

Tags: permutations

The greatest number of points of intersection of 8 straight lines and 4 circles are?
My attempt:Assuming every line cuts all the four circles at two points each, the points of intersection of lines with circles=64.
Now, each circle cuts the other 3 circles at 6 points.Then points of intersection of circles is 6*4=24 making total number of points of intersection 88. The text book answer is 104. How is that?

Comment: While each circle could cut another circle at 6 points, the number of circle-circle intersections is not $6 \times 4 = 24$. That would over count by a factor of 2. Line-line intersections have also been neglected here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of intersections of lines with lines is $7+6+5+4+3+2+1={8 \choose 2}$ and the number of intersection of the circles with circles is $6+4+2=2 {4\choose 2}$. This is because every line intersects with *every other* line and every circle intersects with *every other* circle. Your calculations on the number of intersections of lines with circles is correct at 64.

Answer (score 0):

if we have $k$ circles and $n$ lines, the answer is $2{k\choose2}+{n\choose2}+2nk$, since every two circles intersect at most at two points, every two lines at most one point and every line and circle at most two.

$2{8\choose2}+{4\choose2}+2(8)(4) = 104 $